# With Spring Webclient how to verify hostname validation is taking place

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netty, webclient

I have a project that uses Spring Webclient/Webflux and Reactor-Netty. Our vulnerability scanner detects Netty and complains that it is configured to not do hostname validation by default([CWE-295](https://stackoverflow.com)).

When using Spring WebClient, is hostname validation enabled or disabled by default?
How do I prove WebClient is doing hostname validation?

netty.common 4.1.100
spring boot 3.1.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reactor Netty is not vulnerable by default as it enables hostname verification by default. If you have configured Reactor Netty to use a custom `SslProvider` then you will be vulnerable unless you have enabled hostname verification. You can learn more in [this Spring Boot issue comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/38094#issuecomment-1783358280).